# Aggregation on terms and intervals in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

My documents are like this below:

```json
{
    "uri" : "post:1130a8ef197882bc3ebd",
    "topic_list" : [
        "bye",
        "hello"
    ],
    "datetime" : "2010-06-06T22:08:49"
}
```

I want to make a query to aggregate on both `datetime` and `topic_list`. My desired output is to tell me that on each time interval, how many docs has the `hello` topic in `topic_list`.

What I've tried was this:

```json
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "test": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "topic_list"
        
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But the output just tell me how many docs containing every topic at all times and not in the intervals.
How can I create such aggregation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add two more things:

1. a query to only restrict the results to documents containing the topic "hello". If you're only interested in the document count per time interval, you don't need the `terms` aggregation on the `topic_list` field
2. a [`date_histogram` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html) to create time intervals

Here is the query:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "topic_list": "hello"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "intervals": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "date",
        "calendar_interval": "1d"
      }
    }
  }
}
```